# Show jQModal window on page load

Tags: jquery, jqmodal

I'm playing with jQModal plugin and trying to display its window right after the page is loaded. I used this code in $(document).ready(function():

```
$('#letak').jqm({
    overlay: 70,
    autofire: true 
});
```

autofire setting should do the trick but unfortunately it doesn't work. Works perfectly fine when I click at trigger link.

Example: http://bz.machi.cz/

// Forgot to mention that there is a hidden View link on the page (when you press Ctrl + A you can see it).

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks a lot, Jakub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. I also put together an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/dSZZj/13/) at jsFiddle.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#letax').jqm().jqmShow({overlay: 70});
});
```

Comment: Old answer I know, but it's worth noting that it ought to be:
<code>$('#letax').jqm({overlay: 70}).jqmShow();</code>

Otherwise you are passing the options in the wrong place, and they'll just be ignored.