# Show jQModal window on page load using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, onload, jqmodal

I saw this question:

[Show jQModal window on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884185/show-jqmodal-window-on-page-load)

and works fine when my content is not pulled from a remote source using ajax.

How can I use ajax in jqmodal on page load ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$('#ex1').jqm({ajax: 'path/to/text.html'}).jqmShow({ overlay: 70 });
```